# use same script like jquery or plugins from iframe loaded in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I access an jquery script which I'd loaded in an parent of the iframe.
I tried using `$= parent.$` but then it accesses Dom of parent and not the iframe
Can any one please guide?

Comment: You can't because that iFrame is a different document.

Comment: I set the document.domain as same as the parent.

Comment: Why spend time trying to do the impossible when you can just insert that script link to jquery in the iframe?

Comment: I currently do the same but as i have a number of iframes it seems that its using a lot of browser memory (IE 8)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to access a function that's in the parent documents script.
This can be done providing both documents are located within the same host.
I use this inside the script, that's the file for the iframe.

```
parent.FunctionName();
```

If you want to access a value of a field that's in the parent document you can use:

```
Value1 = $("#FieldNameHere", parent.document.body);
```

Comment: Yes i want to access the functions but the objective is also to avoid multiple scripts in different iframes like jquery. I know that if the url is same the script is loaded from the cache but even then it ends  eating browser memory.

Comment: So then keep all the scripts in the parent page and reference the functions inside the iframe using the above example.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how you can do this. first, you have to define a function that can include javascript files

```
    function loadScript(url)
    {
        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```

Now, you have to get all scripts included on the parent of the iframe and call the loadScript function, just like this

```
    var scripts = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (i=0;i<scripts.length;i++)
        if(scripts[i].src!="")
            loadScript(scripts[i].src);
```